# How can you disable the crafting of certain tool types in Tinker's Construct?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tinkers-construct

I am using Tinker's construct for minecraft 1.7.10. I was wondering if there is any way to disable crafting of tools with certain materials, particularly wooden tools.

I have checked the config file, and there were options to disable certain types of tools, e.g: "Enable mod wooden tools: false". So I set it to false but I am still able to craft wooden tool heads and make wooden tinker's tools.

Answer (score -1):

There is one way made full command blocks! what u need to is...

/testfor @p @e[type={item u want to disable}]

hook that up to a redstone comparator connecting to another command block which has...

clear @p {item}

then hook that up to a repeater and another command block which has...

/give @p {the items you need to craft that item!}

however i have zero idea what tinkers craft is!

Comment: This answer is _not_ applicable. It is wrong in the testfor command (even if it did work) and has _nothing_ to do with command blocks. This question is asking about a Minecraft mod known as "Tinker's Construct", which adds tools and various other items to the game.

Comment: @Alt-F4 While the `testfor` command in this case is not relevant, the implementation of using `clear` to remove items after they are crafted is actually mostly valid.

Comment: @Unionhawk However, the testfor would not prevent infinite item giving by the /give command. You'd need scoreboards to do this properly, and even then, you have to find out how to test for the item.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It could be done in a way that doesn't actually punish the player, but if your goal is to disable wooden items, the better way might just be to punish the player. All they'd lose in that particular case is 1 wooden plank.

Comment: @Unionhawk Nevertheless, this should be disable-able from a config file. Using command blocks with infinite loops is _never_ suggested when an alternate, more stable route exists. How to get there is what the question is asking.